# Apply custom shader from a file at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im experimenting with shaders in unity and what i can do with them.
I was recently wondering if there is a way to apply a custom shader from disk to a material i create in code at runtime.

I have a bunch of self-made vhs shaders in my game, but im no graphics programmer and it would be cool to let users create their own

Answer (score 1):

There is not built/out of the box way in Unity to create a Shader in runtime (This is because Unity shader compiler is in the build pipeline. More information about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-compilation.html)).
Your options are to change between already set shaders like [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-shader.html).

Use the [IUnityGraphics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html) low level interface (Note that requires VERY advanced graphics knowledge and C).

Or using an external library for post processing that enables you to make shaders on the fly like [Unity Post Processing Mod Tool](https://github.com/przemyslawzaworski/Unity-Post-Processing-Mod-Tool).

As you stated that you are not a Graphics programmer, i would really recomend you to take the first route and make a good amount of set shaders or one shader with lots of customizations.